no encuentra la url especificada en java fx
public void cambiarSentidoDelJuego() {
        try {
            Image nuevaImagen = new Image(getClass().getResource("../view/img/sentidoCambiado.png").toExternalForm());
            //Image sentidoCambiado = new Image("file:src/view/img/sentidoCambiado.png");


            String rutaSentidoCambiado = "./src/view/img/sentidoCambiado.png";
            Image sentidoCambiado = new Image(rutaSentidoCambiado);

            if (juego.sentido())
                imagenSentido.setImage(sentidoInicial);
            else
                imagenSentido.setImage(sentidoCambiado);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al cargar la imagen: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

En una aplicacion de javafx, en la interfaz grafica quiero mostrar una imagen. Pero si se da la condicion de cambioSentido un método llama a cambiarSentidoDelJuego para cambiar esta imagen, que es un contenedor del tipo imageView. He revisado varias veces la ruta y es correcta y he probado diferentes formas para acceder a la ruta de la imagen pero ninguna me ha dado resultado.

Primero debes tomar en cuenta que nuevaImagen y sentidoCambiado tratan de cargar la imagen sentidoCambiado.png, asegura indicar la imagen correcta para cada caso.
Con respecto al problema que presentas, este se debe seguramente a que la ruta de donde tratas de obtener la imagen es incorrecta, te sugiero revises que tus imágenes se localicen dentro de:
src -> view -> img -> sentidoCambiado.png

de esta forma cargarías la imagen:
Image sentidoCambiado = new Image(getClass().getResource("/view/img/sentidoCambiado.png").toExternalForm());

